# How Do i select the Min and the Next Min and display both on the same row as correlated query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I used this SQL:

```
/****** Select Min and Next Min with Bike ID  ******/
SELECT
t.[bike_id] 
,min(t.[start_date]) as Min_Date
,(SELECT min([start_date]) From trip Where [start_date] > (SELECT min([start_date]) From trip)) as Next_Min_Date
FROM [dbo].[trip] t
Group By t.[bike_id] 
Having t.[bike_id] < '15'
```

and got this result:

```
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| bike_id | Min_Date                | Next_Min_Date           |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 9       | 2013-08-29 12:02:00.000 | 2013-08-29 09:24:00.000 |
| 10      | 2013-09-01 13:47:00.000 | 2013-08-29 09:24:00.000 |
| 11      | 2013-08-29 20:11:00.000 | 2013-08-29 09:24:00.000 |
| 12      | 2013-08-30 17:15:00.000 | 2013-08-29 09:24:00.000 |
| 13      | 2013-08-29 10:13:00.000 | 2013-08-29 09:24:00.000 |
| 14      | 2013-08-31 11:55:00.000 | 2013-08-29 09:24:00.000 |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Clearly the subquery is not correlated - but I'm not sure how to make this a correlated subquery

What I want is the Next Min Value *FOR EACH BIKE ID* not just the 2nd Min value in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to do this.

```
select [bike_id],
max(case when rnum=1 then t.[start_date] end) as min_date,
max(case when rnum=2 then t.[start_date] end) as next_min_date
from (
SELECT
t.*,row_number() over(partition by t.[bike_id] order by t.[start_date]) as rnum
FROM [dbo].[trip] t
) x
group by [bike_id]
```

Comment: Thank you - SO I tried this and it worked. GREAT!  Could you please point me to some resource that will explain over/ Partition bit of your code?  FYI it complained quite a bit about the multipart identifiers so I had to take them all out of your answer for future people looking at this...

Comment: do you know of a resource that explains about how the **Over(Partition** part of your select statement is working?  I would like to understand how this piece of code actually works :)

Comment: the documentation is a good place to start https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx